# Determine what section a value falls between given a range of values

Tags: excel, function, range

I am trying to write a function in Excel that will return what the Section Number for a given value would be. For instance the `1200` value would fall in Section Number 1, and so on. I am trying to stay away from writing a VBA function to do this.

So what would be a good way to do this?

[image: Section Number]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,$E$2:$G$11,3,TRUE)
```

Assuming your data is in Column E to G and you want Section number in column J. Place the formula in cell J2 and drag it down.

[image]